# How to run shared libs/services as singletons with micro frontend in Angular (Module Federation)

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, angular14, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I have a Monorepo Angular Workspace and I'm using `@angular-architects/module-federation` 14.13.14 and have been following [the documentation](https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/blob/main/libs/mf/README.md#sharing-libs-of-a-monorepo) to create a POC.

I've been trying to run a single instance of a local shared library across my micro frontends but no cigar.

Here's the structure of my workspace:

```
Workspace
|- Projects
   |- shell
   |- app1
   |- lib1
      |- service
         |- name: BehaviorSubject<string>
```

I've used dependency injection to subscribe to `name` on both `shell` and `app1`. I've created a method on `shell` to pass a new value to `name` (`this.lib1Service.name.next('some other thing')`. But this doesn't reflect on `app1`, only on `shell`.

I've added path mapping to `tsconfig.json` as instructed by the author:

```
 "paths": {
   "lib1": [
     "projects/lib1/src/public-api.ts"
   ]
 },
```

According to the documentation, this would be enough in the new version of the plugin:

> New streamlined configuration in version 14+
> Beginning with version 14, we use a more steamlined configuration, when using the above mentioned --type switch with one of the following options: remote, host, dynamic-host. This new configuration automatically shares all local libararies. Hence, you don't need to do a thing.

I've also tried to add the library to the `sharedMappings` array on both `shell` and `app1` `webpack.config.js` files:

```
  sharedMappings: ['lib1'],
```

This is my `shell`'s `webpack.config.js`:

```
const { shareAll, share, withModuleFederationPlugin } = require('@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack');

module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({
  shared: {
    ...shareAll({ singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }),
  },

 // sharedMappings: ['lib1'], // tried uncommenting this but it doesn't work
 },
});
```

EDIT:
I've also tried manually sharing each library as singletons and include the library amongst them in my `shell`'s webpack config file:

```
shared: share({
    "@angular/core": {
      singleton: true,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: "auto",
    },
    "@angular/common": {
      singleton: true,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: "auto",
    },
    "@angular/common/http": {
      singleton: true,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: "auto",
    },
    "@angular/router": {
      singleton: true,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: "auto",
    },
    "lib1": { singleton: true, import: "../lib1/src/public-api.ts" },
    "rxjs": {
      singleton: true,
      requiredVersion: "auto"
    }
  })
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FOR ANYONE WHO STUMBLES UPON THIS THREAD:
I've found the solution. The import in your components that are consuming the service should match the name of your path mapping on `tsconfig.json`.

For example, I've declared my shared lib like this on `tsconfig.json`:

```
    "paths": {
      "lib1": [
        "./projects/lib1/src/public-api.ts"
      ]
    },
```

So, in my micro frontends, I should import the service like this: 
`import { Lib1Service } from 'lib1';`
instead of
`import { Lib1Service } from 'projects/lib1/src/public-api';`

And that's it. Manfred Steyer was right. Once you declared the shared lib in your `tsconfig.json`, you won't need to do anything else (if you're using the `shareAll` approach in your `webpack.config.js`, that is).